# Selecting element with selenium python issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image: I can't select the input field]

I am using this code but I cannot select the input field.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/multiplayer")
input("Start : ")
a = "b"
inputfield = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
inputfield.click()
while a == "b":
    try:
        word = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='highlight']")
        inputfield.send_keys(word.text)
        inputfield.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    except:
        print("Finish")
        a = "c"
```

input field element;

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the page takes some time to load, you should apply explicit wait on the element so that the script waits until the element is present on the page.
You can do it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/multiplayer")
input("Start : ")
a = "b"
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
inputfield = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']")))
inputfield.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,(I've already added an input to wait for the page to load),unfortunately the code didn't work

error code; 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 11, in <module>
    inputfield = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']")))
  line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @AomineDaici Got the issue, there is an iframe which is present on your page, so you need to switch the driver to the iframe and then click on the element. Have modified my code. Please pick the latest code

Comment: You typed the "driver" wrong in 2 places, (browser, 20), browser.switch_to.frame, can you correct ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and interest

Comment: @AomineDaici yeah i made a mistake there, have updated my answer. Thanks!